# Run scala *.jar file from Ubuntu terminal

Tags: scala

I have a compiled `*.jar` file, which is actually Scala code. I want to run this application from a terminal with increased JVM memory. The way I run it so far is:

```
scala MyApp.jar
```

The above works, the app is running.

and this:

```
scala -Dname=Xmx2g MyApp.jar or scala -Dname=-Xmx2g MyApp.jar
```

I do this to use more JVM memory, the app is actually running, but does not seem to use more memory.

How can I run a Scala application (`*.jar` file) with increased JVM memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scala` command requires use of the `-J` option in order to pass options on to the JVM. So, the command line you probably want is:

  `scala -J-Xmx2g MyApp.jar`

FYI, the `-Dname=Xmx2g` would define a system property named `name` and give it the value `Xmx2g`, probably not what you want.